# Missing phone number claim in B2C ID token

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

We have Azure ADB2C connecting to external IDPs such as Azure AD via custom policies. I am able to include given_name, family_name, preferred_username custom claims from Azure AD in the B2C token, however I cant find a way to add a phone number claim. It's not there in the list of custom claims in the token configuration for Azure AD service principal like the other three mentioned above, also I don't see the claim type for it in TrustFrameworkBase.xml. We need to display the phone number of the user on their profile page.

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure AD B2C starter pack, the phone number is stored in the claim called [`strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/SocialAndLocalAccountsWithMfa/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L192).

To add a claim to your token, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#provide-optional-claims-to-your-app).

Add this to your relying party section, under outputClaims:

```xml
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
```

Comment: This seems to be a claim used for multi-factor authentication. Adding it to custom policies didn't pull the regular Office or Mobile phone number from the directory.

Comment: What attribute have you written the phone number to? You can read attributes using the `AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId` technical profile, just add an `outputClaim` there. And finally add an `outputClaim` in the relying party section to put the claim into the token. That can be achieved for any attribute you like.

Comment: What is the name of the phone number attribute? I don't see it anywhere in the base policy. What would be the PartnerClaimType?

Comment: You need to return the user with Graph API and check the attribute name you stored the number in. Likely it’s in the attribute called `mobile` or `strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber`. The partnerClaimType is the attribute name returned via Graph API when returning the user object. In this case, `mobile` or `strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber`.

Comment: None of this works when reading the phone number from external IDP, specifically Azure AD.  We are able to get it from Okta though. We just opened a support case with MS and they suggested to open a support request with Azure AD team.

Comment: AAD doesnt support issuing the mobile number into the token. So AAD B2C cannot parse it. [AAD supported claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#claims-in-an-id-token), [AAD optional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims). If other IdPs issue the claim in their token, then AAD B2C **can** parse it.

Comment: It's part of Open ID Connect supported claims, so this is strange that it deviates from the standard.

Comment: It’s optional. https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims

Comment: It's optional to request it, but there should be a way to request it.